# What is the best way to make a flash drive with many bootable things

Tags: linux, installation, usb-flash-drive, multi-boot, usb-storage

I want to make a flash drive with lots of bootable things on it, a toolkit of sorts. The list of things that I want to boot on it so far it

- Hirens Boot Disk
- Backtrack Linux
- Knoppix STD
- Ophcrack XP
- Ophcrack Vista/7
- Spinrite
- regular linux (preferably centOS)
- MRI Customizer
- and use the rest of the space for regular storage, even available in windows.

The disk is 64 GB so space will not be a problem and I should have plenty left for storage. My question is, how can I make all of these things bootable on one disk. I know perfectly well on separate disks, but not one disk.

Should I make separate partitions? Should I use grub and try to chainload a second tier or programs? Should I make a swap partition for the linuxes to play with when they're being use?

Comment: This question seems to have been answered over at [ubuntu.se] [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/46624/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-with-multiple-iso-images-in-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YUMI works great ! Download [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)!

YUMI (Your Universal Multiboot Installer), is the successor to MultibootISOs. It can be used to create a Multiboot USB Flash Drive containing multiple operating systems, antivirus utilities, disc cloning, diagnostic tools, and more. Contrary to MultiBootISO's which used grub to boot ISO files directly from USB, YUMI uses syslinux to boot extracted distributions stored on the USB device, and reverts to using grub to Boot Multiple ISO files from USB, if necessary.

Comment: does it help me figure out/figure out for me the grub entries? I have had a look at some sites using straight grub to boot extracted ISO images. Pretty deep stuff

Comment: turns out this just does all of the entries FOR me. WAAY EASIER then Unetbootin. Plus Unetbootin didnt support everything I wanted to put on

Answer (score 7):

Answer from [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46624/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-with-multiple-iso-images-in-it)

This is not my content - content taken from link above to avoid link rot

> Creating and installing Multiple Distros in to USB / Pendrive involves two parts:-
>
> - **Creating Multiple Live distro [Using Multicd.sh](https://jeysundar.blogspot.com/2009/05/multi-live-distro-in-single-cddvd.html).** From the link:
>
> "After googling around for few days i found this useful script from www.multicd.tuxfamily.org. Multicd.sh is a shell script written by maybeway36 which enables two or more Live Linux distros / utilities to be able to boot from single CD/DVD. It is really very simple to create multi Live Linux distro in a single disc. Create a folder in your home folder and name it as `multicd`. Put all the live Linux iso images along with multicd.sh script inside multicd folder. Close the window. Open terminal and give the following commands
>
> ```
> cd multicd
> chmod +x multicd*.sh
> sudo ./multicd*.sh
> ```
>
> Above commands will execute multicd.sh. While executing, this script will download few packages from Internet and make a new iso image called multicd.iso for you inside multicd folder. Check the size of multicd.iso image file. If it exceeds more than 700 mb then you must insert DVD to write it. Choose burn image option from your favorite image burning software to write multicd.iso file. Upon reboot, with the CD/DVD present inside CD/DVD drive, new GRUB will display list of live distros available in the disc. Choose your favorite one to login...
>
> Note: When you download any Linux iso image from internet it will look like this "ubuntu-9.04-desktop-i386" but this has to be renamed as ubuntu.iso (inside multicd folder). Presently this script supports 20 live distros. List of Live Linux distros supported in this script are given below (and the names accepted by this script are on the right side of each distro)."
>
> There's a list of distro's on the blog page.
>
> - **Installing Multiple Live distro in to a USB / Pendrive.**
>
> [UNetbootin](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=UNetbootin) [image: Install UNetbootin]
>    allows you to create bootable Live USB drives for Ubuntu, Fedora, and other Linux distributions without burning a CD. It runs on Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X. You can either let UNetbootin download one of the many distributions supported out-of-the-box for you, or supply your own Linux .iso file if you've already downloaded one or your preferred distribution isn't on the list.
>
> Support amongst others: Ubuntu (and official derivatives) 8.04 LTS 9.10 10.04 LTS 10.10 11.04 Daily CD Images, Fedora 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, Rawhide and [lots lots more](https://unetbootin.github.io/).
>
> If you look at them image you can choose distro's or download ISO's yourself and add them or add a custom. And you can set this up on a hard disc or a USB flash drive.
>
> [image]
>
> I hope it is enough information but there is a lot [more info on this blog](https://jeysundar.blogspot.com/2009/06/boot-multiple-distro-from-usb-flash.html).

Comment: will this even work with stuff that isnt a linux liveCD?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean? a liveCD is just a diskimage

Comment: I mean like Hirens Boot Disk or Ophcrack or spinrite. Spinrite isnt even linux based

Comment: Not sure if it will or not - best to try yourself

Comment: @PsychoData I can also see what your trying to learn based up on the packages you want, My personal advise is you will learn so much more if you have a 64gb bootable version of Arch linux (Nothing else) and learn from there - eg. compile your own tools learn to use python, pearl, bash, ect... use packages like Black arch....

Comment: well, Mainly i am using these because my classmates at school arent familiar with any of them and they want something quick and easy to play with. Myself, I usually stick to backtrack. I'd never heard of blackarch, but it looks fairly decent. I'm not a guru by any means (yet!) but I certainly plan to be.

This particular drive I kind of want to be jack of all trades. I will, at some point, get down to a serious pentest thumbdrive, but I dont think I know enough to be able to assemble a proper one yet. I think it would still be too script-kiddie-ish

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10538/discussion-between-50-3-and-psychodata)